# How can I use foreach against object variables?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, foreach, indexing

I have a list of objects with multiple variables within. I have the object displayed on a DataGridView table and I would like to be able to change a specific row on the table corresponding to whatever changes happen to the object that it is reflecting. Here is an rough example of what I want:

```
    foreach (object in objectList where object.specificVariable = value)
    {
        dataGridTable.Rows[object.Index].Cells[3].Value = value;
    }
```

Basically I just want to change only what has been change instead of looping though the entire list and wasting machine time and memory. Efficiency is key. Each variable in the object is displayed on the time and whenever one of the variables change I want grab the index of the object that contained the change only and ignore all the rest.

Comment: I've read your question a few times now and still have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's hard to explain, I have a list of User class objects and a datagridview table that reflects it (user per row). A user has a status, and if the status changes in the program I want it to reflect on the table. I want to find the indexes of each user that has the specific status and then change table entries to reflect the change. The list of users and the table share the same index. So if I can find the index of user based on the status (user.status) I'll be able to change the at the same index. I'd rather not loop through the entire user list, it can get very large.

Comment: @Ozma64 if that's your case (user index = table index) then you could just handle a list of indexes of "dirty" users (users that their status has been chnaged). Then just run through this list. This will only work if you can detect when and which user has been changed, of course.

Comment: yeah and thats the problem, figuring out which users have been changed....im trying to make a list of indexes of all the users with a specific status was hoping if there was a way to query a list for only those users instead of looping through the entire list for them